# How to get the app dimensions with electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

What I want to do is that I want to check if the program takes up any less space than the whole screen. If so, I will enable the horizontal and/or vertical scrollbar accordingly by using the `overflow` property in css.

But how do I get the electron app dimensions? I already know how to get the screen dimensions.

In advance, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` properties of `window`:

```
let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;
```